# Extracting the value of a rate increase

Tags: mortgage

Say I enter in a 30 year fixed rate mortgage at 3% interest a year (in the US). 5 years after, the rates climb to 10% a year for a 25 year mortgage.

Assuming the value of the home stayed constant, the value of the home and the debt has increased because I'm now paying below market interest rate.

One way to extract this value is to hold the mortgage and the house to maturity.

However, if for some reason I want to sell the place, I would have to give up this value, because it would be equivalent to a prepayment, wouldn't it?

Is there any way I can extract this value without owning the property all the way to maturity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if (a) the mortgage is assumable, or (b) you keep the mortgage in place but enter into a long term installment sale.

If the bank holding the loan is local, and kept it in their portfolio, they might settle for less than the remaining value of the note. If I were a banker, getting 3% on $200K, but rates were now 10%, I could settle for say, $150K but get 10% on that money and come out way ahead. As you know, most mortgages are packaged and sold. Tough to pull your loan back out to negotiate.

This seems to be what you intended in your question.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I had in mind. Are mortgages assumable by default, is that something banks offer to individuals ?

Comment: I've had over a dozen mortgages, only one was assumable. Which means nothing. You should ask the bank when you apt for the loan.